# How to rewrite URL in Yaws/Erlang

Tags: erlang, yaws

How can I access yaws file without including it's extension?  Say,

**www.domain.com/listen.yaws** => **www.domain.com/listen**

I could not find any specific documentation for this from `yaws` documentation/appmod.

I think the question is ultimately clarified!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find one example of how to accomplish this in the "Arg Rewrite" section (7.1.2) of [the Yaws PDF documentation](http://yaws.hyber.org/yaws.pdf). Set the variable `arg_rewrite_mod` in your server configuration to the name of an Erlang module supporting rewriting:

```
arg_rewrite_mod = my_rewriter
```

To support rewriting, the `my_rewriter` module must define and export an `arg_rewrite/1` function, taking an `#arg{}` record as its argument:

```
-module(my_rewriter).
-export([arg_rewrite/1]).

-include_lib("yaws/include/yaws_api.hrl").

rewrite_pages() ->
    ["/listen"].

arg_rewrite(Arg) ->
    Req = Arg#arg.req,
    {abs_path, Path} = Req#http_request.path,
    case lists:member(Path, rewrite_pages()) of
        true ->
            Arg#arg{req = Req#http_request{path = {abs_path, Path++".yaws"}}};
        false ->
            Arg
    end.
```

The code includes `yaws_api.hrl` to pick up the `#arg{}` record definition.

The `rewrite_pages/0` function returns a list of pages that must be rewritten to include `".yaws"` suffixes; in this example, it's just the `/listen` page you mention in your question. If in `arg_rewrite/1` we find the requested page in that list, we append `".yaws"` to the page name and include it in a new `#arg{}` we return to Yaws, which then continues dispatching the request based on the new `#arg{}`.